Use of Insecure iOS Coding Functions - React Native, MobSF
We created an iOS .ipa file to upload it on MobSF's Static Analysis to analyze the security of the app. However, we found that there are 2 High Severity issues.
Here is the report that is generated by MobSF IPA Binary Code analysis report.
We haven't used these APIs in our code.
How do we fix this vulnerability in React Native?

The answer is in the last column. Turn off the pointless warnings

How do i do that?

I don't know. You are the one using the tool
